# How to move (drag) a zoomed graph in overview pane?

Tags: gephi

When I'm in overview window and zoom in, some part of the graph is not visible. I want to drag the graph so that I can see it at the zoomed in size.

I tried the "Center on graph" button, but it zooms out the graph and centers it on the screen. I tried the direct and drag tool, which doesn't seem to do anything. What to do to accomplish this?

I want to drag the node in upper left corner so that I can see what it connects to:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this with the mouse. If you want to zoom in on an area, you need to position your mouse over the area you want to see, and then use the scroll wheel to zoom in. So for the case above, zoom out until you can see everything, and then hover your mouse over the area you want to zoom in on (the upper left node in this case), and you scroll your mouse wheel to zoom. That will allow you to zoom in on an area without having to move the object on the canvas first.

Answer (score 11):

Right-click and drag (Gephi 0.9.1 for Mac).

Comment: It took me ages to work out. It's a two finger click, hold, and drag on a trackpad.

Answer (score 2):

To move the graph at a given level of zoom, you can right click.
The keyword was "navigation" :)
Happy work!